# Where does Microsoft Dynamics CRM store OptionSet values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm doing a data migration in to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and need to perform reconciliations against the source to ensure that everything loaded successfully.

To do this I am querying the SQL directly in SQL Server, but I can't seem to find where the OptionSet data is stored. Does anyone know what table(s) it's stored in?

Comment: Are you looking for the selected value or the textual representation?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These are all stored in the StringMapBase table. You'll query via object type code of the entity, attribute name, option set value and language and that'll give you the display value of the attribute.

Comment: Found the data in StringMapBase, but customizations needs to be published before it gets there.

Comment: Nice as I don't have to do any joins.

Comment: See the answer by sarjanwebdev about using the FilteredStringMap view below to avoid breaking changes by Microsoft.

Comment: `SELECT AttributeValue, Value FROM ORGNAME_MSCRM.dbo.StringMap WHERE AttributeName = 'CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME'`  Replace ORGNAME_MSCRM, and CUSTOM_COLUMN_NAME.

Answer (score 12):

Just a reminder! Use FilteredStringMap to continue to be 'supported' by Microsoft!

Comment: Has the FilteredStringMap table been replaced in newer versions? I am trying to retrieve perform a similar task in Dynamics Nav 2018

Answer (score 7):

Here is an SQL Server function to query the stringmap

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_new_GetStringMapValue 
(
    @AttributeName nvarchar(100),
    @AttributeValue int
)
RETURNS nvarchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result nvarchar(4000)
    SELECT @Result = Value
    FROM dbo.FilteredStringMap
    WHERE AttributeName = @AttributeName AND AttributeValue = @AttributeValue

    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

Comment: Modification of SQL database to add such functions is unsupported. If you are hosting this function that reads the FilteredStringMap from another database then it's supported. In the later case, you would use [ORGNAME_MSCRM].[dbo].[FilteredStringMap]